# 「この質問は次でお礼開始が可能でした: 2日後」の意味がわからない

Tags: 討議

質問を投稿した直後のページに「この質問は次でお礼開始が可能でした: 2日後」という文言が表示されましたが、これが何を意味しているのかわかりません。

マウスカーソルをhoverしたときに表示されるヒントもやはり意味がよくわかりません。

もっと適切な訳語を検討した方がいいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

英語では「Bounty」と呼ぶ機能です。専門用語では「Bounty」が「お礼」になっていますが、分かりづらい可能性があります。

目的は自分の信用度の一部を利用し、その質問を注目させるとの機能です。お礼を開始するとメインページのある「おすすめ」タブに現れてきます。質問のベストアンサーを出すユーザーにお礼に出した信用度を与えます。

一つのルールは質問を投稿してから48時間以内にお礼が開始できず、解答をもらう時間を与える必要があります。

> いずれかの回答にお礼をしたい場合は、その回答の左側にあるお礼アイコンをクリックしてお礼してください。 お礼したい回答がない場合は、コメントまたは編集でフィードバックすることをお薦めします。*お礼しない*場合、 お礼を開始した後に投稿された回答のうちスコアが最も高かったもの (最低スコア 2) に、お礼の半分が自動的に渡されることがあります。

英語での文言は：「question eligible for bounty in X hours」
日本語での文言：「この質問は次でお礼開始が可能でした: X期間」
ツールチップ：「より適切な回答に対して自分の信用度から数点付与する」

この文書をどうすればわかりやすいですか？

Comment: なるほど、「お礼」はBountyのことだったんですね。「お礼をする」と日本語で書くと、本当にお礼をすることに見えてしまう（専門用語に見えない）ので、「この質問はあとX時間でBountyが設定できます」という訳がよいと思います。

Comment: @JunichiIto 「Bounty」を書くと英語のStack Overflowになれた方がわかると思うが、初心者がわかるかの悩みがあります。「お礼」がよくなかったら、英語以外の当てはまる言葉はありますか？